# How to make an image according to screen size of each device

Tags: jquery, html, css

Creating a single page responsive website .Implemented a slideshow for my homepage,with the help of this code:

```
<script class="secret-source">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
            height      : 600,
            width       : 1450,
            responsive  : true
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="banner-fade">

    <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
    <ul class="bjqs">
      <li><img  src="<?php print $directory?>/img/a.png" ></li>
      <li><img src="<?php print $directory?>/img/ban1.png" ></li>
      <li><img src="<?php print $directory?>/img/example2.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

</div>...
```

Here slideshow is working fine ,but while placing that code in my device where screen size is 17 inch ,the container is becoming responsive but the image within that container is not responsive.
can anyone help us with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS:

```
.bjqs img { min-width:100%; min-height:100%; }
```

Could also go with:

```
.bjqs img { width:100%; height:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to define the size of the image in terms of %. That should do

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="image_div">
            <img src="images/firstimage.jpg" width=100% align="left">
 </div>
```

CSS for image_div as;

```
#image_div{
width:60%;
float:left;
}
```

Percentages will change the size of content according to your screen sizes. Use width and other properties according to your will.